# Tipo de Variável para persistência em MYSQL Longtext

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring

Bom dia,

Em minha base de dados **MySQL**, possuo uma coluna do tipo **longText.**

Minha duvida é como declarar o tipo e a anotação desta variável na classe java. Em breve pesquisa encontrei a informação seguinte:

```
@Blob
private String meuCampo;
```

isso procede?

Grato!

Comment: Agora fiquei curioso, LongText, sempre usei @Lob no mysql se puder testar outras possibilidade? E postar os Resultados;

Comment: Ok Obrigado, estou implementando, em breve, lhe informo

Comment: Olá, funcionou apenas com a definição jpa1.0

Comment: Opá então vou remover o restante;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Definição JPA 1.0.
@Lob
// Por padrão o tamanho do Text é limitado 65535 bytes.
@Column(name="campo", length=2147483647) 
// No seu caso é LongText 2147483647 bytes.
private String meuCampo;
```